# Where do I cache in a Travis pipeline?

Tags: continuous-integration, yaml, travis-ci

I am currently caching `.npm` and `.cache` in my Travis pipeline. I am unsure of where to place the caching logic. Should I place it before or after the `install` stage? Further, does it matter whether it is placed before or after `install` as long as it is somewhere in the pipeline?

```yaml
language: node_js
node_js:
  - lts/*

cache:
  npm: true
  directories:
    - ~./npm
    - ~./cache

install:
  - npm ci

script:
  - npm run ci:e2e:test

after_success:
  - bash deploy.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

cache in Travis CI always runs on top of the Job Lifecycle defined in your .travis.yml file[1]. If you would like to use caching mechanism of Travis CI defining cache in the top level of your .travis.yml is the way.

You may still define some custom steps before this step, which is called `before_cache`.

[1] https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/job-lifecycle